# ROBLOX script still allows messages through

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I am making a ROBLOX script to block messages which are toxic from getting to other people. For some reason, it isn't working and still allows the toxic messages to be seen by others. Any ideas on how to fix it?

I have tried a super basic filter, which just removes words it finds to be “bad” from a table, and that surprisingly works.

**ONLY SCRIPT:**

```lua
local TextChatService = game:GetService("TextChatService")
local Channels        = TextChatService:WaitForChild("TextChannels")
local HttpService     = game:GetService("HttpService")

local TextClassifier  = "https://api.example.com" -- not actual thing, actual api returns json data
local MaxScore        = 0.7

local function isMessageToxic(message: string, speaker: TextSource): boolean
    if message == "" then return false end
    
    pcall(function()
        response = HttpService:PostAsync(
            TextClassifier,
            HttpService:JSONEncode({
                text = message
            }),
            Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationJson
        )
        response = HttpService:JSONDecode(response).response
    end)
    
    if response.Error or not response then
        print("There has been an error.") -- no body or etc
        return false
    end
    
    if response[1].score > (MaxScore or 0.7) then
        print("Message has been flagged.")
        return true
    else
        print("Message has passed.")
        return false
    end
end

local function channelAdded(channel: TextChannel)
    if not channel:IsA("TextChannel") then return end
    channel.ShouldDeliverCallback = function(message, textSource)
        return not isMessageToxic(message.Text, textSource)
    end
end

for _, channel in pairs(Channels:GetChildren()) do
    channelAdded(channel)
end
Channels.ChildAdded:Connect(channelAdded)
```

**What is sent to the API:**

```json
{
    "text": "i hate you”
}
```

**What it responds with:**

```json
{
    "response": [{
        "label": "NEGATIVE",
        "score": 0.9993651509284973
    }, {
        "label": "POSITIVE",
        "score": 0.0006348910392262042
    }]
}
```

**Image of it not working:**
[image: Filtering not working]

**What is printed:**

```
17:19:59 -- Message has been flagged.
17:19:59 -- Message has been flagged.
```

Comment: I can only think of your API endpoint not processing the chat messages and instead returning no response or a response.Error (making the function return false, thus allowing the message). Can you edit in an example where a toxic message is allowed in, along with the API response?

Comment: Hi, @Ivan, I sent the body of the POST request and the response of the API. I’ll get an image of it not working once I get out of school.

Comment: `response` is global? Could some other code be overriding it? (Not sure if it's possible for Roblox to yield here, for vanilla Lua I would say no...)

Comment: @tehtmi this is the only script that I have in the game, and i don’t think it can be used in all scripts unless under _G or getgenv or whatever

Comment: Again, I'm not super familiar with Roblox, but even with just this as the only script, it seems there could theoretically be self-interference from multiple instances of just this callback running concurrently (depending on where yielding can occur).

Comment: @tehtmi I checked, and for every one person in the server it printed “Message has been…” everytime someone had talked. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't know. It does seem surprising. I guess there can be multiple channels, but I don't know if a message would go to multiple channels or if there's a reason it would be once for each player. If the response is the same every time, it shouldn't matter if one overrides the other, but maybe there is something else happening. In general I would recommend trying to get more information to narrow down where something strange happens (e.g. adding more prints or using other debugging tools). (And I still think it's a good idea to declare `response` as local in the top level of `isMessageToxic`.)

Comment: @Ivan I've added an image of it not working and what the console responds with (couldn't get the image, and the score is the positive score. you can try here: https://www.roblox.com/games/9429848079/Toxicity-Filter